# What happens to free games obtained through PlayStation Plus after it expires?

Tags: ps3, psn, playstation-plus, psone-classics

I bought a three months membership for PlayStation Plus some time ago. This membership has already expired. While it was active, I got the classic PSOne Resident Evil titles for free. Will I be able to re-download them now without having to purchase a new PSPlus membership?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You will not be able to re-download them, or play any games that you had previously downloaded & installed via Playstation Plus. If you try to download any of the games from your download history, it will not work.

However, if you later decide to renew your subscription, these games will become available for use again. They are even re-downloadable, as long as you added the games to your cart and successfully checked out before their free offer period passed.

> **Q: How long do I get to keep the free games with PS Plus?**

> A: Games you get with PS Plus are free to download with a PS Plus membership. As long as you are a PS Plus member, you’ll always have access to any game you’ve added to your library, even if you’ve previously deleted a game from your hard drive.
>
> **Q: If a game is no longer available for free with PS Plus, can I still download it for free with my PS Plus membership?**
>
> A: If you did not add a game to your library when it was free with PS Plus, you will not be able to secure your free download. However, if you added a game to your library when it was available for free, but it’s no longer on your hard drive, you can visit the PlayStation Store and re-download it anytime, as long as you’re a PS Plus member.
>
> **Q: How many times can I download / re-download a game in the Instant
> Game Collection?**
>
> A: Download a game as many times as you like, even if it’s been deleted from your PS4 hard drive, as long as you’re a PS Plus member.

**Q: What happens to the games and add-ons I download for free through a PS Plus membership if I decide to not renew my membership?**

> A: If you do not renew your PS Plus membership, you won't have access to previous free games downloaded with PS Plus. If you have purchased add-ons for a game you received free with PS Plus, and the add-ons require the free game to play, you will not be able to access the add-ons if you choose not to renew your membership.
>
> Should you decide to re-activate your membership, you can again play all free games downloaded, along with all purchased add-ons for these games. Alternatively, you may also purchase the specific game to access any purchased add-ons for the game.

More information can be found at PSN's Support page [here](https://www.playstation.com/en-us/support/subscriptions/subscribe-ps-plus-download-monthly-games/#download) and [here](https://www.playstation.com/en-us/support/subscriptions/cancel-playstation-plus/).

Answer (score 9):

Once your PlayStation Plus (PS+) membership expired all "free" games (and DLC) obtained will not be accessible until you renew your subscription.

Attempting to launch an expired game will launch a message that says "This content can be used if you renew the license in PlayStation Store." You'll then be redirected to the PlayStation Store, where you will be able to purchase the expired title.

- All "free" games (and DLC) obtained from PS+ **WILL** be expire.
- Free themes and avatars do **NOT** expire.
- Anything that you've purchased at a discounted price will **NOT** expire.

[See Section 10a of the PS3 Terms of Service, "Subscription Services"](http://legaldoc.dl.playstation.net/ps3-eula/psn/e/e_tosua_en.html).

If you (sign in to) resubscribe after your subscription expires, the games will work again. You will not have to re-download them.

Answer (score 3):

You will not be able to play them. I am not sure if you can download them or not. PSN prompts before the purchase of these titles that they are only valid as long as your a member.

Renewing your subscriptions will open these games back up or you can purchase them. If you have not had your subscription for more than 3 months the only thing you will lose is your games saves that were in the PSN cloud.