# Do I lose access to games I've downloaded when they're removed from the Instant Game Collection?

Tags: playstation-plus

If I download a game from the Instant Game Collection, and it is later removed from it, can I still access it? Do I keep it till I delete it or unsubscribe?

PS Plus seems like a great deal but it would suck if I lose access to games I am only halfway through.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What happens to free games obtained through PlayStation Plus after it expires?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/76543/what-happens-to-free-games-obtained-through-playstation-plus-after-it-expires)

Comment: @Kappei Different question. Previous question was regarding subscription expiration. This question is about free games' availability by Sony.

Comment: @JohnoBoy the answer touches also this subject anyway, giving a detailed explanation of what happens in this case

Comment: @Kappei Agreed, but the fact the answer for the first answers both doesn't make this a duplicate. the user may not have known to search for the answer for his question on that one

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll still have access to the games you've downloaded, even if they're removed from the collection or you've deleted them off your system, as long as you're still a subscriber.

If your subscription ends, you won't be able to access those games, but they'll still be available again if/when you resubscribe.

Comment: You don't even have to download them, you can just add them to your library, they will stay available. It is useful if you want to play something later when your disk is full.