# Playstation + subscription and games

Tags: psn

If I hypothetically purchase games that are discounted because I am playstation+ member do I get to keep the game after the end of the subscription?

Comment: I'm certain this exact question was asked before, but I either can't find it, or it was deleted.  In any case, see [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/76543) very similar question for what happens to **free** games after your subscription expires

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Games you purchase are there to stay after the subscription lapses; only completely free games/DLC from Playstation Plus will be revoked if your subscription lapses (note you get access back if your subscription is renewed, even if it has previously lapsed).

A modal warning will appear *every time* you "purchase" a PS+ free game warning you that you will in fact lose access if your PS+ subscription ends; when in doubt, look for this warning. There's no such warning on free/paid items you'll keep after PS+ is over.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the game is yours after purchasing.