# Will the Rotation games stay forever even after new rotation?

Tags: ps3, psn, playstation-plus

Let's say I download Uncharted 3 because it is on this month's rotation, when the month ends and a new rotation begins, will I still be able to play uncharted?

Can I keep a "free rotation" game forever by being a Playstation Plus member?

Comment: You can find the answer you seek [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/76543/what-happens-to-free-games-obtained-through-playstation-plus-after-it-expires). Basically: `If you did not download the game when it was in the collection, you will not be able to secure your free download. However, if you downloaded when it was in the collection, but it's no longer on your hard drive, you can visit the PlayStation Store and re-download it anytime, as long as you're a member.` The same also applies to *playing* the game.

Comment: So you can Keep a "rotation" game forever as long as you are a member?

Comment: Yes, and re-download it in case you delete it from your console.

Comment: @Peter do not edit someone's answers, ask in comments, or update your question. And concerning your edit, yes as long as you have "purchesed" or downloaded PS+ game and have not interrupted your PS+ membership it's always available for you (I think that's that I wrote in answer already).

Answer (score 0):

The @Nolonar comment is somehow different to my expirience, but I'm a member is a Russian segment of PSN, so it could possibly differ.

Basically during the rotation, you must "purchase" the game with a price of 0. If you "purchased" the games it's not necessary to even download them, they will be available "forever" till you are member. The additional requirement, your subscription mustn't be interrupted. If you make a pause in subscription you *could* lose your free games (but not necessarily will).